# How do I make sure my ajax calls are always successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have this function that constantly uploads browser data to server by jquery post. Interval is as soon as every second. It seems that some requests don't make it to the server.

The question is how do I make sure every ajax requests are successful. Re-post until it's successful? One thing to consider is `data` has a high chance of being overwritten by upcoming `upload()` instances when one instance is known failed. So need to preserve the original `data` in failed instance too.

```
function upload(){          
    $.post(
        ajaxURL,
        {history:JSON.stringify(data)}
    );  
}
```

Comment: What i'd be asking is, why is it failing? Have you put in an error callback?

Comment: You could use Ajax Queue Manager

Comment: You'll have to show all the relevant code that is involved in repeatedly calling this function and acting on it's results.  Only then could we advise on the proper way to handle this.

Comment: @Sudhir Maybe a comment isn't the place for this, but I'd be curious to know if you're aware of and can recommend any such queue managers that are mature and have a good (or at least well-documented) API.

Comment: Yes it may be my poor server or internet connection that's causing the fail. And I think this is the point I need to handle that failure, not in the server.
That upload() function is called everytime a div on the document has changed. No error handling is implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

$post has success, error and complete methods like that;

```
$.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

taken from JQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
so you can re-post in error part